# SAXON Append a child to XdmNode

Tags: java, xml, saxon

I am using SAXON JAVA API.

Can someone tell me a way how to append a Child Element to an existing XdmNode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XdmNode object is primarily designed to represent the input or output of a query, stylesheet, or XPath expression; it's not designed as an interface like DOM or JDOM for programmatic construction of XML trees within your Java application. Probably the best way to add one XdmNode C as a child of another XdmNode P is to write the query

```
declare variable $P as element() external;
declare variable $C as node() external;
element {node-name($P)}{$C}
```

and then execute it from your Java application, supplying the two nodes as query parameters.